# how to remove/set values at once in all comoboxes in jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a scenario where I have many combo boxes, more than 20. I do not want to write code to clear each comobox and set values to each. Rather, I need to write functions which can take all comoboxes, iterate through those and remove all values. Also, I have a list of values which I should be able to set. List of items is same across all comoboxes.

Answer (score -1):

Try below line of code.

```
private void clearAllComoboxes(JFrame frame){
        Component[] components = frame.getComponents();
        for(Component component : components){
            if(component instanceof JComboBox){
                ((JComboBox) component).removeAllItems();
            }
        }
    }
private void setValuesToComoboxes(JFrame frame, Set<String> values){
    Component[] components = frame.getComponents();
    for(Component component : components){
        if(component instanceof JComboBox){
            for(String value : values){
                ((JComboBox) component).addItem(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Read more @ https://softwaretestingboard.com/qna/536/how-clear-all-comoboxes-once-jframe-and-add-values-same-once#axzz4wM3UEZtq